# Backup Server docs and sql files with Grive

Tags: 12.04, server, backup, google-drive, grive

Has anyone ever used [Grive](https://github.com/Grive) for Ubuntu Server backs up to Google Drive?

How safe would this be?

(Not sure if my "anti-google" boss would like it too much but still)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grive is not the first tool that would try to use google drive space as a remote backup tool; it started with one that used gmail+fuse to emulate a disk drive on mails.

How safe would it be? I think you know the answer. Beta software, unsupported by the disk space owner, as a matter of fact, banned by the disk space owner (read terms & conditions). No, it is not safe at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an online service to access Google Drive through WebDAV (e.g. using http://synqya.appspot.com)